# How to politely enquire how serious someone is when they say "work for me as a postdoc"

Tags: postdocs

I am a PhD student that is about to graduate. Sometimes professors whom I know personally (and/or have collaborated with before) will say "Come work in my lab as a postdoc!".

However, when I approach them after a few days/weeks/months, they inform me they would like to hire me, but do not have any funding.

Personally I would rather they not have not said "Come work in my lab as a postdoc" if they weren't sure they would have the funding, but I understand their reasons for saying such things.

However, in future, how can I politely enquire how serious they are about how interested (and able) they are in hiring me?

Comment: I would interpret that sentence as "I encourage you to apply", nothing more.

Comment: How can you see how serious they are? Ask them if they have or will soon post a job. On the other hand, my post-doc job was gotten in a very short conversation, when the director I knew of an interesting institute came up to me at a conference and asked me when I could start...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would follow up the verbal conversation with an email.  For example

> Thanks for the encouraging words the other day about a possible postdoc.  I wanted to check, were you talking about a funded position?  Where would I find instructions for submitting an application?

Depending on the vibes you got, you might want to start with something less formal, for example

> Thanks for the encouraging words the other day about a possible postdoc. I was wondering whether the position might be available for the upcoming semester.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them!!! If you're having a conversation, and they mention that, it could be a serious proposal or could be a throwaway compliment. You could ask "I would be interested in that - did you mean it seriously?" or "I'd be interested - do you have funding available?"